# group_concat and frequency of each word in this record

Tags: mysql, sql, word-frequency

This is my database.

Tables:

```
item: item_id, name
order: order_id
orderform: order_id, item_id, quantity
```

Data in tables

```
item_id  name
1        ball
2        cap
3        bat

order_id
1
2
3
4

order_id item_id quantity
1        1       2
1        3       4
2        1       1
3        2       3
3        1       2
3        3       1
4        1       2
```

At the moment I'm using following sql query:

```
SELECT order_id, group_concat(name)
FROM order
LEFT JOIN orderform
  ON order.order_id = orderform.order__id
LEFT JOIN item
  ON orderform.item_id = item.item_id
GROUP BY order.order_id
```

Which gives me this look

```
order_id         name    
1                ball,ball,bat,bat,bat,bat
2                ball
3                cap,cap,cap,ball,ball,bat
4                ball,ball
```

But I want it to look like this

```
order_id  name
1         2 x ball,4 x bat
2         ball
3         3 x cap,2 x ball,bat
4         2 x ball
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go 2 steps:

First: Resolve the items and create the text

```
SELECT 
  orderform.order_id AS order_id,
  CONCAT(orderform.quantity, ' x ',item.name) AS txt
FROM order orderform
LEFT JOIN item ON orderform.item_id = item.item_id
```

then group by order

```
SELECT
  order_id, 
  group_concat(txt) AS txt
FROM (
    SELECT 
      orderform.order_id AS order_id,
      CONCAT(orderform.quantity, ' x ',item.name) AS txt
    FROM order orderform
    LEFT JOIN item ON orderform.item_id = item.item_id
) AS baseview
GROUP BY order_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works exactly as I needed.

Comment: I have one more question. Some rows in orderform may have two rows of same order_id and same product and this will result in displaying select like this "2 x ball, 2 x ball". Is there a way to and up same kind items to show it like this "4 x ball". Thanks

Comment: For some unknown reason everything got multiplied by 9. So lets say the record should show "2 x ball" it shows " 2 x ball 2 x ball 2 x ball 2 x ball 2 x ball 2 x ball 2 x ball 2 x ball 2 x ball"

Comment: Solved. I only need to apply DISTINCT to group_concat function "group_concat(DISTINCT txt)"